# CMD: How do I delete all the contents of all directories (in the current directory) without deleting the directories themselves?

Tags: batch-file, command-line

For example:

I'm in the directory:

> F:\Data

Inside this directory, I have four directories:

> F:\Data>dir
>   22179  22915  23459  23460

These directories have various content, including directories and files.
I'm trying to run something like:

> rmdir /s *\*

where I delete all the contents of these numbered directories, while leaving the empty directories. Is there a one-liner that can do this, or do I have to loop through the sub-directories?

Comment: `del /s /q *.*` should do it, but not a programming question

Comment: I do not actually know if what I'm asking is possible. I am seeking a clean simple, solution to what I feel should be a simple problem, but I don't know if the Windows command line can do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(for /d %A in (*) do @for /d %B in ("%A\*") do @rd /s /q "%~B")&del /s /q *.* >nul
```

It's a one liner - but I wouldn't call it simple. It loops through the 1st two levels of the tree, but everything deeper will be removed without more looping. If in a batch file then %A and %B become %%A and %%B

I wasn't sure if you wanted all files deleted from your root (F:\data in your case). The above will delete files found in your root.

If you want to preserve the files in root, then I think this should work (I didn't test this one)

```
for /d %A in (*) do @(@for /d %B in ("%A\*") do @rd /s /q "%~B")&@del /q "%A\*.* >nul
```

The @ symbols can be removed from both sets of code - they are just there to prevent each level of the command from being echoed.

Comment: The first line does exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try this I think this will help....

**RD /s /q (and then the path to folder which is to be removed)**

it will remove all the contents with the folder itself

Answer (score 1):

Does `DEL /S /Q *.*` work for you?

Comment: That gets pretty close, but it leaves more than the top-level subdirectories.

Comment: That is, if I have a directory 22179\Docs, it doesn't remove that directory and I would like it to.